Does anyone know how to add radio buttons to a custom policy in Mulesoft 4?
I am creating a custom policy and would like it to have radio buttons. Currently, that field looks like this in my json schema file:
"RadioButtons": {
       "type": "string",
       "title": "Radio Buttons",
       "enum": ["Option1 value", "Option2 value"]
    }

This renders as a drop-down in the policy configuration UI, which is not what I want; what do I have to do to set up actual radio-button fields on my custom policy?  I have been pouring over Mulesoft's documentation about creating custom policies, but their docs on creating the json schema file are very sparse.  I do not have access to the uischema file used by Cloudhub, so unless I can include my own custom uischema, changing which widget is used doesn't seem to be an option; I have to do it all through the json schema.
Any help would be much appreciated.
EDIT FOR ADDITIONAL CONTEXT:
My question is referring to the json schema file you upload when adding a policy to Exchange:

The .yaml definition file defines the properties for the policy, but the json schema is what creates the UI in API Manager:

Here is the current content of my json schema file:
{
  "title": "BPDCustomPolicy",
  "type": "object",
  "description": "Custom Policy Test",
  "properties": {
    "policymessage":{
        "title": "Policy Message",
        "type": "string",
        "description": "The message that the policy will send to the api"
    },
    "policyarray":{
        "title": "Policy Array",
        "type": "array",
        "description": "The policy will send this array along with the request.",
        "items": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "policychbox1":{
        "title": "Policy Check Box 1",
        "type": "boolean",
        "description": "This is unchecked by default."
    },
    "policychbox2":{
        "title": "Policy Check Box 2",
        "type": "boolean",
        "description": "This is checked by default.",
        "const": false
    },
    "RadioButtons": {
        "type": "string",
        "title": "Radio Buttons",
        "enum": ["Option1 value", "Option2 value"],
        "enumNames" : ["Option1","Option2"]
    }
  },
  "required":[
    "policymessage",
    "policyarray",
    "policychbox1",
    "policychbox2"
  ],
  "@context": {
    "@vocab": "anypoint://vocabulary/policy.yaml#",
    "security": "anypoint://vocabulary/policy.yaml#"
  },
  "$id": "basic-authentication-simple",
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema"
}

Sorry for any confusion I've caused.  Again, I would appreciate any help I can get.
EDIT FOR MORE CONTEXT:
I already had a .yaml definition file:
#%Policy Definition 0.1
id: BPDCustomPolicy
name: BPDCustomPolicy
description: BPDCustomPolicy
category: Custom
type: custom
resourceLevelSupported: true
encryptionSupported: false
standalone: true
requiredCharacteristics: []
providedCharacteristics: []
configuration: 
  - propertyName: policymessage
    name: Policy Message
    description: The policy will send this message along with the request.
    type: string
    optional: false
    sensitive: false
    allowMultiple: false
    defaultValue: "This is the default message"
  - propertyName: policyarray
    name: Policy Array
    description: The policy will send this array along with the request.
    type: array
    optional: false
    sensitive: false
    allowMultiple: true
  - propertyName: policychbox1
    name: Policy Check Box 1
    description: This is unchecked by default.
    type: boolean
    defaultValue: false
    optional: false
    sensitive: false
    allowMultiple: false
  - propertyName: policychbox2
    name: Policy Check Box 2
    description: This is checked by default.
    type: boolean
    defaultValue: true
    optional: false
    sensitive: false
    allowMultiple: false
  - propertyName: RadioButtons
    name: Radio Buttons
    description: Property Description
    type: radio
    options:
    - name: Option1
      value: Option1 value
    - name: Option2
      value: Option2 value
    optional: true
    sensitive: false

As you can see, it has the radio button control defined.  If you look at the screenshot for the Cloudhub publishing wizard, it asks for both a json schema and a yaml definition file (the metadata file).

What is this JSON file? A Mule 4 custom policy uses a YAML file to describe it's configuration. Share the actual file or explain in more detail how are you configuring this policy. And note that API Manager is the component that manages policies, not CloudHub. Also you won't have access to modify the platform UI. That's expected.

This is the json schema file you upload when adding a policy to Exchange.  I am aware that API Manager manages the policies on an api; the json schema file is what provides the UI controls when configuring the policy (there is a .yaml definition file as well, but you still need the json schema for the UI elements).

Note it is Mule 4. MuleSoft is the company name, not the product name.

The YAML file is used to define the types for the UI:

A YAML file
It defines the configurable parameters of the policy. Anypoint API
Manager uses this file to render the UI to display inputs for the
policy.

Radio buttons is one of the types used for properties defined in the YAML file.
Example:
- propertyName: RadioButtons
  name: Radio Buttons
  description: Description
  type: radio
  options: # Radio button options
  - name: Option1
    value: Value1
  - name: Option2
    value: Value2



Please see my updates to the question.
